# How to remove the related videos from a Youtube video played using <iframe> tag in html?

Tags: html, iframe

I need to remove related videos showed at the end of the video played using the iframe tag.

Actually I used Bootstrap-4  modal and play the video. At the end it shows some related videos. I just need to get rid of that. Even though I applied rel=0. But it didn't work. Can some one give me a helping hand.

```
         .modal-content
           .modal-header
             h5#exampleModalLabel.modal-title 
             button.close(type='button' data-dismiss='modal'
                      aria-label='Close') Play                           
           .modal-body
              iframe.vid-modal__iframe( src="************?rel=0" frameborder="0"  
                allowfullscreen=""  allow="autoplay")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `&` in front of `rel=0` because when you are adding more parameters to the url it should be separated by the `&` character and if adding any query to the url it should be separated by the `?` character, because everything after `?`character is treated as query string in the url. so your url should look like this.

`"https://www.youtube.com/embed/videos?list=PLS0dR_j-EZXZ4ouzQRYrejG926iH5JliC&rel=0"`